# Route specific traffic to specific interface

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface

I have two NICs. Basically, I want to use one of them for specific traffic (based on the destination IP or the domain) and the second one for the rest of the trafic.

Is this possible? If it is, How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is partially possible.

You can route traffic based on IP to a certain interface through judicious manipulation of your system's routing table. Specifics of how to do this are extremely dependent on your specific goals, but in general you're looking at `route add` commands. This requires that the upstream connections be able to handle the types of routing you're doing as well.

You cannot route based on domain unless you go up a level to the application layer (e.g. Apache), and then you're no longer manipulating anything in the OS you're manipulating one or more applications.